# Hibernate don't persist in database

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm new in using spring mvc and this is my first application , so I Followed a  tutorial and I have a problem . When I run the server(Tomcat ) , hibernate don't persist or add table in mydatabase , when I drop the schema It cause a warning :

```
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown database 'tests')
```

So I understand that there is no problem with the connection with the database .

this is the pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.springmvc</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<java-version>1.7</java-version>
<org.springframework-version>4.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
<version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
<version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
  <finalName>SpringMVC</finalName>
 </build>
</project>
```

This is the applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Enable autowire -->
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tests" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entities" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">test</prop>
            <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

and this is s simple entity class (user.java ) :

```
package com.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int id;

private String name;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

There is no error in the console , but there is no table created in the database , please help !!!!

Comment: Why do you think Hibernate should create tables? The job of Hibernate is to map existing tables to entities. It *can* create tables during development to help you in the beginning, but that won't happen if you're not telling it to do it. And you chose not to let it create tables by commenting out the property that makes it create tables.

Comment: So your question is not about creating tables, but about persisting data. Where is the code used to persist data?

Comment: Fix the issue, "Unknown database 'tests'", first